# Qt6 Android cursor select handle can't follow textarea when open keyboard

Tags: android, qt, qml

Qt environment: Qt6.2

Why is the bubble selection handle at the bottom, it should always be near the cursor.

[image: this is issue picture]

Textarea code:

```
TextArea {
                    id: messageField
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    placeholderText: qsTr("Enter your message")
                    wrapMode: TextArea.Wrap
                    selectByKeyboard: true
                    selectByMouse: true

                    leftPadding: 14
                    topPadding: 10
                    bottomPadding: 10
                    background: Rectangle {
                        radius: 6
                        color: "#f1f1f4"
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching and finding, this is a [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-100436) that the Qt team is fixing.